# python Incorrect formatting Cyrillic

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def inp(text):
    tmp = str()
    arr = ['.' for x in range(1, 40 - len(text))]
    tmp += text + ''.join(arr)
    print tmp

s=['tester', 'om', 'sup', 'jope']
sr=['тестер', 'ом', 'суп', 'жопа']
for i in s:
    inp(i)
for i in sr:
    inp(i)
```

Output:

```
tester.................................
om.....................................
sup....................................
jope...................................

тестер...........................
ом...................................
суп.................................
жопа...............................
```

Why is Python not properly handling Cyrillic? End of the line is not straight and scrappy. Using the formatting goes the same. How can this be corrected? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:

- http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Basically, what you have in `text` parameter to `inp` function is a string. In Python 2.7, strings are bytes by default. Cyrilic characters are not mapped 1-1 to bytes when encoded in e.g. utf-8 encoding, but require more than one byte (usually 2 in utf-8), so when you do `len(text)` you don't get the number of characters, but number of bytes.

In order to get the number of characters, you need to know your encoding. Assuming it's utf-8, you can decode text to that encoding and it will print right:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8
def inp(text):
    tmp = str()
    utext = text.decode('utf-8')
    l = len(utext)
    arr = ['.' for x in range(1, 40 - l)]
    tmp += text + ''.join(arr)
    print tmp

s=['tester', 'om', 'sup', 'jope']
sr=['тестер', 'ом', 'суп', 'жопа']
for i in s:
    inp(i)
for i in sr:
    inp(i)
```

The important lines are these two:

```
    utext = text.decode('utf-8')
    l = len(utext)
```

where you first decode the text, which results in an unicode string. After that, you can use the built in `len` to get the length in characters, which is what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. Accurate and detailed response. Thank you again.